# Eclipse Shortcut to add access specifier to all fields?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not sure could be silly, but far important for me set find out shortcuts to add say "private" key words to all the Member Variables in java class.

I followed so many links, but did not find any satisfactory answers : https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/25-eclipse-shortcut-keys-for-code-editing.

I have almost 40+ fields in Pojo class and none of the field has access specifier.

Could anyone please suggest shortcut for the same?

**student.java**

```
public class Student {
    String id;
    String name;
    String clz;
    .......
    .......
    ........
}
```

Comment: Are the field look like what you post in your example(One line one field)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for Eclipse on Windows/Linux.

1) Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to ***Toggle block selection*** (Toggle block / column selection in the current text editor), this will allow you to write vertically in Eclipse.

2) Put the cursor at the beginning of the first line, then press <kbd>shift</kbd> key and move the cursor down with the <kbd>↓</kbd> key to select the lines you want to provide modifier, like this.

[image]

3) Type in the modifier:

[image]

For Macos, the key combination for multi-line edits in Eclipse is <kbd>option/alt</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Block mode, my very first thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find and replace`

Just mark your linke line this;

```
^    String^ id;
    String name;
```

mark range is between `^` and `ctrl+f` to find (if I am not mistaken and didnt confused that with intellij)

use find and replace to find `Strign` and replace with `private String`

if you have not only `Strings` here you can use reges to replace `^\\s+` with `private`. That regex matches begining of the line and bland any number of blank characters.